# MS ACCESS 2016 - Sort greyed out in table design mode

Tags: ms-access

We recently upgraded from ACCESS 2003 to ACCESS 2016.  In 2016, I am unable to sort on a column, bound to a lookup, in an ODBC linked table, in design view.  The sort option is greyed out for this column, while other columns can be sorted.  Sorting works fine when using ACCESS 2003.  Any help?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're trying to set a default sort order to the linked table? Why not set this on the form? I didn't think you could make any changes in Design View of a linked table though.

Comment: No form.  Just trying to sort the table in design mode.  Works on other columns just fine.  You actually can make some (limited) changes to a linked table, in this case, the only change was that a lookup was added.  All of this works fine in previous versions (2003, anyway... Still looking to confirm it worked in 2013)

Answer (score 1):

Got it!

In the lookup table I was using (also a linked ODBC table (and actually a view at that)), I had two columns:  the ID column and a [Description] column that pulled together bits and pieces from other tables into a concatenated text string.  For reasons unknown, ACCESS 2016 insists that the [Description] column is a "Long Text" data type (formerly known as "memo" data type), while earlier versions make no such assumption.

Looks like I have approximately 120 views in which I need to tack on "CONVERT(varchar(100)," in order to convince ACCESS 2016 that it's not a memo field... because reasons.